# Code formatting in Scala is wrong with multiple line string

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I am asking this question after tackling this question:

[How to test akka-http route to handle exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66026596/2359227)

There is a lot of code there, bur as you can see the formatting is not correct for the first piece of code. It's treated as if it's a string. Let's consider the following example:

```scala
""" this is a string "this is still a string" another quote: " after the quote """
```

As you can see, `this is still a string`, and `after the quote` is not formatted as a string, although they should be. The rule is that single quotes are just part of the string when they are surrounded by triple quotes.

[Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/UrjOZxlFSOSQ7C7Ez7FIKQ) is a code run that helps demonstrating this.

### Update

I've created [this](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/2987#event-4299707266) github issue which was fixed and merged.

Comment: Since you tagged the code block as `scala`, and the [[tag:scala]] tag [does indeed use the `lang-scala` highlighter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info#prev-value), it appears the issue would be with the highlighter itself.